# how to get all value from WHERE IN in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i return all the value when using count + where in in mysql?

mysql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count , promocode FROM `dat_booking` WHERE promocode IN ("ABC","DEF","XYZ") GROUP BY promocode;
```

result:

```
count  promocode
3      ABC
6      XYZ
```

But i also want if it don't have value in table dat_booking it return 0

I want:

```
  count  promocode
   3      ABC
   0      DEF
   6      XYZ
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: do you have promocodes in another table? I mean if you have some static table where is all types of promocodes?

Comment: Yes, without the value "DEF" preexisting I think you would have to create a temporary table first, and use an outer join, before you could *create* a record "DEF" to cross-reference.

Comment: @Godot yes , i have another table store all promocde

Comment: That is new information, and creates a *different* (simpler) question. I suggest that you remove this question and try again to provide a clear question, with all relevant information.

Comment: i have a list of promocode include used or not used , now I want to know how many times code used to make a report , So I think the new table is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 as req, promocode,count(*) FROM `dat_booking` WHERE promocode IN ("ABC","DEF","XYZ") GROUP BY promocode union select 2 as req, 'XYZ', 0 order by req
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have another table for static values of *promocodes*:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as count , 
`dat_booking`.promocode 
FROM `dat_booking` LEFT JOIN `some_static_promocode_table`.promocode 
ON `some_static_promocode_table`.promocode = `dat_booking`.promocode 
WHERE `dat_booking`.promocode IN ("ABC","DEF","XYZ") GROUP BY 
`dat_booking`.promocode;
```

Comment: Try ask what OP wants... he never said static values are in another table however it's the best solution ^^

Comment: I asked above and he wrote he has static table :)